# How to update a column (all rows) based on current value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with a column called "CreatedDate" (type: DateTime). I want to update all records by adding 3 hours to existing value. All rows are created on a different DateTime.
If a record was created at 07:33 then after running the query it should have value 10:33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATEADD`:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET CreatedDate = DATEADD(hour, 3, CreatedDate);
```